# Order SPARQL query results by length of a string?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to autocomplete what the user writes in an input, with terms in DBpedia, similar to [this jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/lawlesst/a00x2ess/). Try writing **dog** in the input of that jsFiddle, and you will see the 'Dog' term in the suggestions.

I have the following code, and the problem is that the 10-term list I got as a result does not contains the "Dog" alternative. So, if I could order the list by the length of the (string representation of) **?concept**, then I could get that term.  Is this possible?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?concept
WHERE {
  ?concept a skos:Concept . 
  FILTER regex(str(?concept), "dog", "i")
}
ORDER BY ASC(?concept) LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, if I could order the list by the lenght of the ?concept it is possible to get the term. But I can't find the right statement to do it. Is it possible?

It sounds like you're looking for **[strlen](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strlen)**.

```sql
order by strlen(str(?concept))
```

E.g.,

```sql
select distinct ?concept where {
  ?concept a skos:Concept . 
  filter regex(str(?concept), "dog", "i")
}
order by strlen(str(?concept))
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fconcept%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fconcept%20a%20skos%3AConcept%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20regex%28str%28%3Fconcept%29%2C%20%22dog%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20strlen%28str%28%3Fconcept%29%29%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That said, if you're just checking string membership, you don't need all the power of regular expressions, and it *might* be more efficient to use **[contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains)** and **[lcase](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase)** to check whether the lowercased *?concept* contains *"dog"* with a **filter** like:

```sql
filter contains(lcase(str(?concept)), "dog")
```

The table of contents in the SPARQL spec has a big list of functions that you can browse.  In particular, you'd want to look at the subsections of [17.4 Function Definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#SparqlOps).